# What is the big O notation and how do I calculate it?

Tags: algorithm

Calculate big o of function. How do I calculate the big O notation in this function?

Example:

```js
function fun1(int n)
{
  int s = 0;
  for(int i = 0; s < n; i++)
  {
    s += i;
    for(var j = s; j < n; j++)
      {
        console.log(j);
      }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a broad example of what big O notation is? (and then I agree it's a dupe)? Or do you want your example being calculated and explained? (and then I disagree it's a dupe) ?

Comment: Oh. I want to calculate big O with simple function in this case. :)
Thank u.

Comment: @amit Feel free to dupe-close to this target instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I disagree, this is a specific question about a specific piece of code.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like we're doing his homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, consider the `i`-th iteration of the outer loop. After execution of the loop's body,

```
s = 1 + 2 + ... +  i-1 + i
```

which is equal to `i*(i+1)/2 = (i²+i)/2` by an identity by Gauss. The maximum value for `i` such that this expression is smaller than `n` is can be obtained by elementary calculation as follows. If we require

```
(i²+i)/2 <= n
```

which means

```
i²+i-2n <= 0
```

we can use the formula for [reduced quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation) to obtain

```
i <= -1/2 + sqrt(1/4+2n)
```

which is in `O(n^{1/2})`. In each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop takes `n-s` iterations, which very roughly can be estimated by `n` (but this is very imprecise, I believe the overall analysis can be made more precise). In total, this yields a bound of `O(n^{1/2}*n)=O(n^{3/2})`.

Comment: Did I mess something up?

Comment: Please prove that `sum{n-s}` is indeed `Theta(nsqrt(n))`. The O is obvious, but not the lower bound, and thus I am really not sure this bound is tight. (For example, `sum{2^i | 0 <= i <= logn}` is not `Theta(nlogn)`, please show that this phenomena does not occur in here as well, and the bound is not too relaxed.

Comment: @amit In fact, I guess this bound is *not* tight. I'm thinking about it.

Comment: It's tight. Getting s to n/2 requires Theta(sqrt(n)) iterations, and in each iteration, we do n/2 work in the inner loop.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't understand why we do `n/2` work in the inner loop; do you mean in each iteration or in total? If the latter, why?

Comment: @Codor Each iteration where s < n/2.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Perhaps I misread something, but the inner loop's index starts at `s`, so if `s<n/2`, *more* than `n/2` iterations of the inner loop are done?

Comment: @Codor Yes, it's an argument for the matching lower bound.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Oh yes, I was confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Codor: 
1. "The inner loop takes n-s iterations" 

=> I agree with you.

2. "Which very roughly can be estimated by n (but this is very imprecise, I believe the overall analysis can be made more precise)"

=> how can you prove that it's estimated by n. Can you interpret  and explain its proving? :)

Comment: @CongDinh By this argument I mean `n-s <= n`.